# How do i edit my uitable property?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I have a figure of uitable. I have 4 row and 3 columns.When i go to the property inspector, i cant delete row number 4. How can i delete row number 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the help to [UITABLE PROPERTIES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitableproperties.html), it says:

> The number of columns in the table is the larger of ColumnName and the
>   number of columns in the Data property
>   matrix or cell array.

The same applies to rows.

If you use the default row and column names ('numbered'), the easiest way to get your table to be the right size is to define an `defaultData` in the command window that has the correct number of rows/columns (in your case, `defaultData = zeros(3,3)`, and set `data` property to that value.

Comment: can you give the example? because i try it before but when i run the program, its still the same

Comment: where should i put defaultData = zeros(3,3)? at uitable callback or pushbuttons or opnfunc?

Comment: @slumberk: While you have GUIDE open, you go to the command-line, then evaluate the expression, so that you have an array `defaultData` in your workspace. Then you click on the icon next to the property `data` in the property inspector, and select `defaultData` from the list. This should fix the table.